# Form: Post field values to different fields depending on radio selection

Tags: javascript

I'm building a registration form where registrants have to give their phone number.
As I'm storing land line and mobile in separate contact fields, I need to know which one they are submitting.
I know I can provide the 2 form fields, but want to have the form frontend as simple as possible.

Therefore I've just one text field for the number and radio buttons for selecting land line or mobile.
The value of the text field should be posted in one of 2 hidden fields, based on radio selection.

I could also ask before the input field pops up with correct contact field, but that doesn't look good.

Phone number

```
<label>Is this a cell phone or a land line?</label><br>
<input type="radio"  class="radio1" name="question" value="1">Land Line</input><br>
<input type="radio"  class="radio1" name="question" value="0">Cell Phone</input>

<input type="hidden"  class="text" name="land line"></input><br>
<input type="hidden"  class="text" name="cell phone"></input><br>
```

Comment: Explain this line please **The value of the text field should be posted in one of 2 hidden fields, based on radio selection.**

Comment: OK, the value of text field in form frontend should be placed in one of to fields which are not visible for the registrant.
The 2 fields are mapped to 2 contact fields in database.
So the radio buttons should post to correct hidden field, mobile or land line.

Answer (score 0):

The input which you will give to the first input will be given to the hidden field on select of the radio button. If any previous value is given to the hidden fields will also be made empty

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.radio1').change(function(){
if($(this).val()==1)
{$('#landline').val($(number).val());$('#phone').val('')}
else
{$('#phone').val($(number).val());$('#landline').val('')}

})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="number"/><br>
<label>Is this a cell phone or a land line?</label><br>
<input type="radio"  class="radio1" name="question" value="1">Land Line</input><br>
<input type="radio"  class="radio1" name="question" value="0">Cell Phone</input>

<input type="hidden"  id="landline" value='' class="text" name="land line"></input><br>
<input type="hidden" value='' id="phone"  class="text" name="cell phone"></input><br>
```